# React: How to get a Django CSRF Token if CSRF_TOKEN_HTTPONLY is true?

Tags: django, reactjs, fetch, django-csrf, django-2.1

I'm building a React application for a Django backend. In the backend the security setting [`CSRF_TOKEN_HTTPONLY`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY) is set to `True`. How can I obtain this csrf token in a React app? The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/#acquiring-the-token-if-csrf-use-sessions-or-csrf-cookie-httponly-is-true) only describes how to do that using jquery. I'm usin the `fetch` API for my http requests.

Comment: You probably want to update the question to include a code snippet showing what you’ve tried so far. And if you haven’t tried anything so far, you might want to do that first.

Answer (score 0):

If you include the csrf token in your HTML like the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/#acquiring-the-token-if-csrf-use-sessions-or-csrf-cookie-httponly-is-true) says:

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

Then you can simply get the token like this:

```
var csrftoken = document.querySelector("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").value
```

And do your requests with the Fetch API this way:

```
fetch(url, {
    credentials: 'include',
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
      'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
    },
    body: {}
})
```